# Docker COPY lost intermediate path

Tags: docker

Dockerfile and build context file tree, the `core-site.xml` file's relative path IS `conf/etc/hadoop`

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── conf
    ├── etc
    │   └── hadoop
    │       └── core-site.xml
    └── xxx.conf
```

Dockerfile(very simple) as below

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data
WORKDIR /data

COPY conf/* /data/
```

After `docker build -t any/any:any .`, the `COPY` layer's file list as below. Intermediate path **etc/** of file `core-site.xml` lost. Where the **etc/** gone ?

```
data/
data/xxx.conf
data/hadoop/
data/hadoop/.wh..wh..opq
data/hadoop/core-site.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` so you just have `COPY conf /data`

The `COPY` command treats the copying of files and directories a bit differently. Your `COPY` statement expands to

```
COPY conf/etc /data/
COPY conf/xxx.conf /data/
```

The first statement actually copies the contents of `conf/etc` into the `/data` directory on the container.